# How to run rails request specs on a cloud deployment?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, selenium, integration-testing

I am new to rails testing.  Two days of running down leads with Google has turned up no solutions for what ought to be a frequent need.

If I write request (integration) specs to use a Selenium or other browser-based driver, is it possible to redirect the test's i/o to a staging deployment on a cloud server (in my case Heroku)?

If so, how?  If not, what prevents this from working?

So far I have been using rspec/capybara, but would switch to anything of similar power if necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Capybara with Selenium driver, and set `Capybara.app_host` to specify the IP of you staging app server. While doing so you can turn off Capybara local rack with `Capybara.run_server = false`

Remote testing will allow you only to perform human kind of action and test the returned generated HTML/JS/Json etc .. but no access to controller, view, or any other app internal objects.

On thing you could do (I never tried, but I don't see why it wouldn't work) is to set-up your database.yml test configuration to remotely access you staging database, allowing you to control the database during your tests. It's not really secure so you may want to do that over a SSH tunnel , or a similar solution.

Comment: Thanks very much.  This is very helpful.  I'll try it.  What is the best place to set Capybara configuration?

Comment: Capybara is not stand alone, it sits above your test suite. So if you use rspec you must configure Capybara in your spec_helper.rb file. See here for all info: https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara